# Two different PHP sessions in same domain, how to destroy only one of them?

Tags: php, session

In the same domain I have two applications running

- `localhost/app1`
- `localhost/app2`

Here is my session management:

**Page for check the login:**

```
session_start();
//...check if the login is correct

//if is correct
$_SESSION["SESSION_VALID"] = true;
//redirect to the correct page

//if is not correct
$_SESSION["SESSION_VALID"] = false;
//redirect to the login
```

**A page of my application:**

```
//check the session
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['SESSION_VALID']){
    //redirect to login page
    header("Location: ../../login/");
    exit;
}
```

**Logout page:**

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
//redirect to the login
header("Location: ../login/");
```

---

Now, back to the initial problem. I have already read several questions on Stack Overflow related to this problem. The solution would be to use the `session_name("app1")` before every `session_start()`.

Ok, but now the problem is another: when I logout from one of the application, how can I set which session should be destroyed? Just call `session_name("app1")` before the destruction of the session? Is the correct solution? Something like that?

```
session_name("name_of_the_session_to_destroy");
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location: ../login/");
```

Comment: Since you are running two apps: to make the sessions independent of each other, you can set the cookie validity for the session to extend to each specific sub-directory.

Comment: In logging off another application, is your purpose to ensure a user cannot be logged onto both apps at the same time? So, if they log onto one they log off the other automatically?

Comment: the user can be logged in simultaneously on both sessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have two applications on the same domain but want to operate two sessions entirely independently of each other. You are finding that logging off one app logs the user off the other app, but you don't want this to happen.

The solution is to set the session cookie only to be valid for the directory part of the domain for each app. By default, sessions extend across the whole domain, which is why destroying the session in one app affects the other one too.

For example, to log onto app 1, do this at the start of your session:

```
session_set_cookie_params (60 * 30, '/app1');
```

Of course, you will need to detect which app you are in, and serve the right path component accordingly. You can get this from a `$_SERVER` variable.

[Read more here](https://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

Comment: ok , so i should set the cookie only on the checklogin.php page , correct ? (and only in case of correct login, obviously)

Comment: @WhiteLine: You can do this just before `session_start()` on every page, and regardless of whether the user logs in correctly. A cookie will be set regardless of whether you use this - this just specifies some features of the cookie.

Comment: i have insert this `session_set_cookie_params (60 * 30, '/app1');` at the top of the page checklogin.php of the app1 and this  `session_set_cookie_params (60 * 30, '/app2');` at the top of the page checklogin.php of the app2.  Currently always use the variable `SESSION_VALID` in both sessions (is a problem?). And also by setting cookies, when I login in one of the two applications, the login is enabled on both.

Comment: Try clearing your cookies and starting again - maybe you have old cookies active. I've not tried this function myself, so maybe it needs to be called immediately _after_ the session start? Play around, experiment a bit. It absolutely will work, this is what that parameter is for.

Comment: It's fine to have the same session variable in both apps - once they create independent sessions you can use whatever names you like.

Comment: I tried to set the cookie before/after the opening of the session (on the checklogin page of both app), but when I login on app1, i can enter automatically on the app2

Comment: Check your cookie validity using a browser plugin (e.g. Web Developer on Firefox). You've done something wrong, and it needs to be debugged. Read the manual page to reassure yourself that this _is_ the way to do it.

Comment: i check the cookie with google chrome. actually the values do not appear to have been set correctly. I did a test by setting the id of the session : `session_id("testID"); session_set_cookie_params(60 * 30, '/app1'); session_start();` , and doing so the data (the time of the session and the path) are set correctly ... I have to use a sessione_id ?

Comment: Make sure all pages have this code on, including the log off page. If the cookie values have not been set correctly, find out why. Read the comments on the appropriate manual page. This is essentially a debugging problem.

Comment: you mean this code ?  `session_id("testID"); session_set_cookie_params(60 * 30, '/app1'); session_start();`

Comment: ok the problem is finally solved. "enough" to enter the set of cookies in every page where I open the session. thanks for your patience

Comment: I don't know what `session_id()` does, I don't think you need it. If that sets the cookie **value** then it needs to be long and hugely random, so that users do not pick up the sessions of other users. Pleased you solved it though.

Comment: After searching for hours, I finally got this. I have 3 PHP web apps on the same server in different directories, so each time I logout of one, it logs off the other 2 apps immediately. Been playing around with a custom session_id('YOUR_ID_HERE') till I got this workaround. I am using Zebra Session - a drop-in replacement for PHP's default session handler which stores session data in a MySQL database. It worked for me like magic! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the logout button url, you can give a GET parameter like ?app=1 or ?app=2, so you know which app to close. If you know the session name of the app you can close it with the following:

You can use `unset($_SESSION['SESSION_NAME']);` you unset a specific session.

Comment: this is not only for the session variables ?

Comment: What do you mean by that?